# How to return a png file using FS

Tags: node.js, file, discord.js, fs

I was creating a DiscordJS Bot that is going to return a file saved in my local folder using FS. It can open and close folders, but the problem is, I need to return a png file, not its name. Right now, it only returns the name of the file, rather than the file itself.
Is there any way I can return the file rather than its name?
If needed, I will add the code itself, however, I think there is no need for the code since this is a theoretical question rather than a practical question.

Comment: It would actually be really helpful if you would add you code in here as it will enhance our understanding of your concrete problem. 

Actually, the `fs` module by nodejs can return the file data in byte arrays which you can then upload to discord in order to display it as a message.

Comment: Can you consider being slightly more in-depth as your question is considered as an un-understandable question as there is such minimum depths of explanations, is there any code snippets or any test runs or errors that you have encountered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just worked for me locally as it would read in the file buffer and send it as an attachment to the corresponding discord server channel.

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] })
const fs = require('fs')

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)

  client.guilds.cache
    .get('760214655120965664')
    .channels.cache.get('760214655653117963')
    .send({
      content: 'anyFile',
      files: [
        { name: 'file.png', attachment: fs.readFileSync('./packages/client/public/fav.png') },
      ],
    })
})

client.login('yourtoken')
```

Outcome:

[image: outcome picture]

Documentation/Reference: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send